# Solve[] not solving my system of the nonlinear equations in three variables

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

Given the eigenvalues

```
m = {{M1, 0, -4.28345, 42.8361}, {0, M2, 7.9998, -80.001}, {-4.28345, 7.9998, 0, -mu}, {42.8361, -80.001, -mu, 0}} 
{eigenval,eigenvect} = Eigensystem[m,Quartics->True]
```

I need to solve the system

```
{eigenval[[2]] == m1, eigenval[[3]] == m2}
```

in order to get `M1,M2` as functions of `mu` (to simplify the evaluation, `m1, m2` can be put equal to 50 and 200 respectively).

I tried

```
Solve[eigenval[[2]] == 50 && eigenval[[3]] == 200,{M2,M1},
  Assumptions-> M2 > 0 && M1 > 0 && mu > 0]
```

but after over an hour I had to stop the evaluation.
The same went for

```
NSolve[{eigenval[[2]] == 50, eigenval[[3]] == 200},{M2,M1,mu},
  Method -> {"UseSlicingHyperplanes -> False}]
```

Could someone please tell me if the evaluation is worth the long wait or if there are better/ faster approaches?

I wrote the matrix because the expressions of the two eigenvalues alone were extremely long, every suggestion involving the charactertistic polynomial must make sure that the two eigenvalues considered are precisely the second and third.

Comment: btw, what is your eig2 and eig3 in your example? Please post complete and self contained code that can be copied and pasted as is.

Answer (score 1):

In 13.3 on Windows 10

```
FindInstance[eigenval[[2]] == 50 && eigenval[[3]] == 200 && M2 > 0 && M1 > 0 && 
mu > 0, {M2, M1, mu}]
```

> `{{M2 -> 3178570902975/8577048221, M1 -> 1515/28, mu -> 5583/26}}`

Comment: Thing is I need the functions M1(mu) and M2(mu). I tried also Reduce[] but doesn't seem to get to the end of the evaluation.